# Cannot set std::map elements?

Tags: c++, clang, std

I'm a really bad C++ programmer, but for work I have to rewrite a numeric library from Python to C++.
Since I have a lot of constants, I decided to store them in a `std::map`.
So I have a `vector_dict.h` file, which contains the following `typedef` (I'm using the armadillo library for vector-related calculations):

```
namespace klib {
    typedef std::map<std::string, arma::vec> vector_dict; // a map of strings to vectors, used to store particle and interaction data
}
```

Then I have a `particledata.h` file, which contains

```
#include "vector_dict.h"
namespace klib {
    extern klib::vector_dict atom_data;
    extern klib::vector_dict molecule_data;
}
```

and the implementation in `particledata.cpp` looks like this:

```
#include "particledata.h"

arma::vec klib::atom_data["N"] = arma::vec::fixed<4>();
double klib::atom_data["N"][0] = 14.0067;  // nitrogen atom mass, atomic mass units
```

I'm using XCode (Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4)), and it shows that there's an error in both lines: specifically, it says "Size of array has non-integer type 'const char[2]'.

Just to test what's going on, I made a separate project, where everything's in one file, and the following code compiles just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    typedef std::map<std::string, arma::vec> vector_dict;
    vector_dict vv;
    vv["N"] = arma::vec::fixed<4>();
    vv["N"][0] = 34.5;
    vv["N"][1] = 44.5;
    vv["N"][2] = 54.5;
    vv["N"][3] = 64.5;
    return 0;
}
```

So where did I mess up?

Comment: Is the code in particledata.cpp in a function or just floating about?

Comment: It's just floating around – I was planning on using the `atom_data` map as sort of a global variable from which I would load data given user input.

Comment: Why do you even need map for constants?

Comment: @keltar Because he wants to look up by string. Although it has some performance cost, for non-performance critical project, this is perfectly acceptable in my book.

Comment: @NeilKirk perhaps, but they could be [accidentially] modified. That said, *if* there were a reason for that at all.

Comment: @keltar Yes, I want to look up by string, that's the main reason. It gets loaded after the lookup into class data, so the performance overhead is only during the lookup/loading part, then it's just class fields of type `double`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not too clear from your code snippet, but it looks like you might be putting that code in the middle of nowhere in particledata.cpp and not in a function. Try this instead.

header file:

```
namespace klib
{
    extern const klib::vector_dict atom_data;
}
```

source file:

```
namespace
{
    klib::vector_dict create_atom_data()
    {
        klib::vector_dict atom_data;
        atom_data["N"] = arma::vec::fixed<4>();
        atom_data["N"][0] = 14.0067;
        return atom_data;
    }
}

extern const klib::vector_dict klib::atom_data = create_atom_data();
```

I made the map const to prevent it being modified after creation, which can prevent accidents. If you do want to modify the map after its creation, just remove the consts from the code above.

Comment: Works, thanks! And thanks for the `const` addition, I forgot C++ has that.

Answer (score 2):

The lines

```
arma::vec klib::atom_data["N"] = arma::vec::fixed<4>();
double klib::atom_data["N"][0] = 14.0067;
```

are erroneous. The `atom_data` is already defined - you do not need to (even cannot) specify type during assignment. Try

```
klib::atom_data["N"] = arma::vec::fixed<4>();
klib::atom_data["N"][0] = 14.0067;
```

Comment: Tried this – now it also gives the following error: "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations".

Comment: It should be inside initialisation function that you'll call before using this values.